# What is crossrange and downrange for an entry vehicle?

Tags: reentry, entry-descent-landing

I have been searching the terms online but still can't get a more intuitive understanding. If you could refer me to some website, book or if you could offer me an explanation I would really appreciate it!
Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Downrange is the distance traveled in the direction of flight. Imagine the orbit of a spacecraft as a circle around the Earth, '[downrange](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265999443_Orion_Capsule_Handling_Qualities_for_Atmospheric_Entry/figures?lo=1)' is the distance traveled along this path. When you do a ballistic (uncontrolled) reentry, this is the path you travel.

[image]

Crossrange comes into play when you make a turn, and you deviate from your orbit. It's the distance between the spacecraft and the path of its original orbit.

[image]

My own image, it's a top view of the original orbit and the effect of making a turn early in the reentry trajectory.

The Shuttle was capable of a large crossrange distance on reentry: they wanted to be able to land ~2000 km away from the orbital path. This meant they could launch from Vandenberg in California into a polar orbit, make 1 orbit and then land back in California. That 1 orbit took 90 minutes, in which the Earth rotated by ~2000 km, so a downrange landing would put the Shuttle in the Pacific, 2000 km off the West coast.

Comment: IIRC, the crossrange capability was a USAF requirement as they were going to buy some shuttles too. Then they didn't and NASA was stuck with the design.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your explanation and the paper helped me a lot!